# React Components - Passing values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need some help:

1. How to use value `name` from `LoginPanel` component after user write it inside the input and click button and use it inside the `App` component.
2. How to render `LoginPanel` as first and if input name is written and button is clicked switch view to the App component?

I can't understand that.

My code looks like that.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function LoginPanel() {
  const [fname, setName] = useState({
    fName: "",
    password: "",
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setName(prevValue => {
      return {
        ...prevValue,
        [name]: value
      };
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>
        Log In ↓
      </h1>
      <form>
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="fName"
          value={fname.fName}
          placeholder="First Name"
        />
        <input
          type='password'
          name="password"
          placeholder="Password"
        />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default LoginPanel;
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Note from "./Note";
import CreateArea from "./CreateArea";

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

  function addNote(newNote) {
    setNotes((prevNotes) => {
      return [...prevNotes, newNote];
    });
  }

  function deleteNote(id) {
    setNotes((prevNotes) => {
      return prevNotes.filter((noteItem, index) => {
        return index !== id;
      });
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <CreateArea onAdd={addNote} />
      {notes.map((noteItem, index) => {
        return (
          <Note
            key={index}
            id={index}
            title={noteItem.title}
            content={noteItem.content}
            onDelete={deleteNote}
          />
        );
      })}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import App from "./App";
import LoginPanel from "./LoginPanel";

function Main() {
  const [isLogged, setLogged] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {!isLogged ? <LoginPanel /> : <App />}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Main
```

I tried a lot of react tutorials and documentation.
I want use value `name` from `LoginPanel` component after user write it inside the input and click button and use it inside the `App` component and to render `LoginPanel` as first and if input name is written and button is clicked switch view to the `App` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for help!
I changed the code.
It works and looks like that:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function LoginPanel({ onLogin }) {
    const [fname, setName] = useState({
        fName: "",
        password: "",
    });

    function handleChange(event) {
        const { name, value } = event.target;

        setName(prevValue => {
            return {
                ...prevValue,
                [name]: value
            };
        });
    }

    function login(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        onLogin(fname.fName);
    }

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>
                Log In ↓
            </h1>
            <form onSubmit={login}>
                <input
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="fName"
                    value={fname.fName}
                    placeholder="First Name"
                    required
                />
                <input
                    type='password'
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default LoginPanel;
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Note from "./Note";
import CreateArea from "./CreateArea";

function App({ loggedName }) {
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
    function addNote(newNote) {
        setNotes((prevNotes) => {
            return [...prevNotes, newNote];
        });
    }

    function deleteNote(id) {
        setNotes((prevNotes) => {
            return prevNotes.filter((noteItem, index) => {
                return index !== id;
            });
        });
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <h1>Hi {loggedName}</h1>
            <CreateArea onAdd={addNote} />
            {notes.map((noteItem, index) => {
                return (
                    <Note
                        key={index}
                        id={index}
                        title={noteItem.title}
                        content={noteItem.content}
                        onDelete={deleteNote}
                    />
                );
            })}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import App from "./App";
import LoginPanel from "./LoginPanel";

function Main() {
    const [isLogged, setLogged] = useState(false);
    const [loggedName, setLoggedName] = useState("");

    function handleLogin(name) {
        setLogged(true);
        setLoggedName(name);
      }
      
      return (
        <div>
          {!isLogged ? (
            <LoginPanel onLogin={handleLogin}/>
          ) : (
            <App loggedName={loggedName}/>
          )}
        </div>
      );
}

export default Main
```

Answer (score 1):

Lift the "name" state up to the parent, `Main`, and pass the state and state updater function down as props to the components. When the form is submitted, update the state.

For more details see [Sharing State Between Components](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components).

Example:

```
function Main() {
  const [loggedName, setLoggedName] = useState("");
  return (
    <div>
      {!name ? <LoginPanel setName={setLoggedName} /> : <App name={loggedName} />}
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
function LoginPanel({ setLoggedName }) {
  const [fname, setName] = useState({
    fName: "",
    password: "",
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setName(prevValue => {
      return {
        ...prevValue,
        [name]: value
      };
    });
  }

  function login(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setLoggedName(fname); // <-- update parent state
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>
        Log In ↓
      </h1>
      <form onSubmit={login}> // <-- form submit handler
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="fName"
          value={fname.fName}
          placeholder="First Name"
        />
        <input
          type='password'
          name="password"
          placeholder="Password"
        />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}


export default LoginPanel;
```

```
function App({ loggedName }) {
  ... do what you need with the passed loggedName prop ...

  ...
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you.
I changed the code and read the article you provided.
I hope to understand more now the working of this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the name useState hook in the Main file and pass it as a props to the LoginPanel, Also pass the same hook to the App file to use the data inside.To switch between App and LoginPanel:- pass the isLogged hook to both of them and write a function inside both the files to switch when a button is clicked.